# Table not appearing when web scraping in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an interesting thing happening and I can't figure out what is going on. I am trying to web scrape from this HTML:

```html
<div class="table_wrapper setup_long long setup_commented commented" id="all_roster">
 <div class="section_heading assoc_roster" id="roster_sh">
 <span class="section_anchor" data-label="Roster" id="roster_link"></span><h2>Roster</h2> <div class="section_heading_text">
 <ul><li>*ProBowl, +<a href="/about/allpro.htm">1st-tm All-Pro</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div><div class="placeholder"></div>
 <!--
 
 <div class="table_container" id="div_roster">
     
     <table class="per_match_toggle sortable stats_table" id="roster" data-cols-to-freeze=",2">
     <caption>Roster Table</caption>
     
 
    <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
    <thead>      
       <tr>
          <th aria-label="No." data-stat="uniform_number" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" data-tip="Uniform number" >No.</th>
          <th aria-label="Player" data-stat="player" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc show_partial_when_sorting left" >Player</th>
          <th aria-label="Age" data-stat="age" scope="col" class=" poptip sort_default_asc center" data-tip="Player's age on December 31st of that year" >Age</th>
```

The table I want to pull is the 'Roster' table. Theoretically I should be able to use pd.read_html(link, match = 'Roster') however when I do that it shows no results. In fact when I just do pd.read_html the return is the expected list but with only one table. I went into the HTML and confirmed that the table existed so I decided to try with BS.

```py
table = soup.find_all("div", id = 'all_roster' )
table[0]
```

As you can see the table exists... but I cannot for the life of me get beautiful soup or read_html to find the table. It's like everything after "<!--" doesn't exist. Anyone have insight?  table[0].findAll('tr') returns an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

The table is inside HTML comments `<!--`/`-->`, so to parse it remove the comments and use e.g. `pd.read_html`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/kan/2023_roster.htm"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

div = soup.select_one("#all_roster")
df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(div).replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")))[0]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     No.                    Player  Age  Pos   G    GS     Wt     Ht                       College/Univ   BirthDate   Yrs    AV                             Drafted (tm/rnd/yr)
0   73.0           Nick Allegretti   27    G  17   1.0  310.0    6-4                           Illinois   4/21/1996     4   1.0    Kansas City Chiefs / 7th / 216th pick / 2019
1   97.0      Felix Anudike-Uzomah   21   DE  17   0.0  255.0    NaN                         Kansas St.   1/24/2002  Rook   1.0     Kansas City Chiefs / 1st / 31st pick / 2023
2   81.0                Blake Bell   32   TE  17   3.0  252.0    6-6                           Oklahoma    8/7/1991     8   0.0   San Francisco 49ers / 4th / 117th pick / 2015
3   32.0               Nick Bolton   23   LB   8   8.0  237.0   5-11                           Missouri   3/10/2000     2   4.0     Kansas City Chiefs / 2nd / 58th pick / 2021
4   40.0             Ekow Boye-Doe   24   CB   6   0.0  171.0    6-0                         Kansas St.   11/4/1999  Rook   0.0                                             NaN
5   26.0                 Deon Bush   30   DB   6   0.0  200.0    6-0                         Miami (FL)   8/14/1993     7   0.0         Chicago Bears / 4th / 124th pick / 2016
6   89.0              Matt Bushman   28   TE   1   0.0  245.0    6-5                                BYU   11/3/1995     2   0.0                                             NaN
7    7.0           Harrison Butker   28    K  17   0.0  199.0    6-4                       Georgia Tech   7/14/1995     6   5.0     Carolina Panthers / 7th / 233rd pick / 2017

...
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had something to do with that but didn't know that's how comments function in HTML.